# How to get number of users who had a specific product in the payment page

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to get how many users had a specific product while they were on the payment page.

For instance, my website sells fruit, I want to see how many users from Las Vegas had Apple in their shopping cart while they were on the payment page. 
so Fruit will be my product category, Las Vegas is location which is tracked in the Customer Dimension.

I know there is Product Check measures, but that's how many times, I would like to know the distinct count of users.

```
SELECT           
      Date
     ,count(DISTINCT FULLVISITORID) AS QulifiedVisitor    

FROM `61626111.ga_sessions_*` as t         
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS hit         
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hit.customDimensions) AS customDimensions 

where hit.page.pagepath ='/booking_path/payment' 
   and date between '20180401' and '20190430'
    and customDimensions.value='Las Vegas'
group by date
```

Comment: Hi Rachel, can you please advise what's is not working in the sql you provided and an example of expected result

Comment: I see you are using Google Analytics data, do you Advanced E-commerce activated?

Comment: I agree that it is required to know more details about the question. Please help us address the Tamir and Ben's comments.